# What is the definition of polygonal loop?

Tags: k-theory

How to prove "every loop can be uniformly approximated arbitrarily closed by a quotient of polynomial loops?"  In Blackadar's book, the proof is completed with the help of "polygonal loops," but what is the definition of "polygonal loops?"

Comment: Have you checked the index of Blackadar's book for polygonal loops?

Comment: I have checked,the definion is not given!

Comment: I would suppose that a polygonal loop is a loop in the form of a polygon.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly sure polygonal loop here means piecewise linear. The proofs in Blackadar can be pretty vague.

For a more detailed proof see either:

- Lemma 11.2.3 in "An introduction to K-theory for C*-algebras" - Rordam, Larsen & Lausten; or
- Lemma 9.2.4 in "K-theory and C*-algebras" - Wegge-Olsen.

Comment: But  in Blackadar's book ,A is a local Banach algebra,while In Olsen's book and Rodam's book.A is assumed to be a C* algebra!

Comment: True, but I don't imagine this particular proof relies on the C*-identity in any way. It should be fairly easily transferable.

Comment: I assume that the coefficients are related to A